# envio PDF adjunto correo node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, email

Hola tengo un problema para adjuntar un PDF usando sendgrid y nodejs, he intentado TODO, no entiendo por que no envia el adjunto, enviá el correo mas no el adjunto, acá parte del código para ver si ven la falla, de antemano gracias....

```
             FS.readFile('/home/ec2-user/apinodev2/TOS.pdf', function(err, archivo) {

                var options = {
                to: [nick.email],
                subject: 'Registro',
                attachments: [{
                      filename: 'TOS.pdf',
                      content: archivo,
                      contentType: 'application/pdf'
                              }]
                              };
```

He colocado, path,    disposition: 'attachment' y nada, no se donde tenga un error...

pd: debo hacerlo a traves de un callback por versiones del servidor....

Comment: falta la parte donde envías el correo

Comment: el correo se envia sin problemas, lo que no hace es adjuntar el documento...

Comment: yo lo comento por que no se si lo tengas dentro de el evento que ya cargo el archivo, o fuera, y no te tome el archivo, por que es asíncrono.

Comment: la otra opción que veo en su documentación en github, siempre le adjuntan la opción  `disposition: 'attachment'`, dentro de el objeto de el archivo a enviar [Attachments](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/attachments.md)

Comment: ya lo habia probado igual no funciona, gracias por tus minutos igual